# Сортировка по двум полям с выводом уникального связанного содержимого

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть таблица "Новости" с полями:

```
id_news       int(11)
name          tinytext
body          text
putdate       datetime
objavlenije   enum('yes', 'no')
```

Нужно сделать сортировку по двум полям с выводом уникального связанного содержимого из этой таблицы. в начале должен быть вывод новостей по дате в количестве 10 шт. с значением `Yes` в `objavlenije`, а потом - вывод всех оставшихся новостей по дате, вне зависимости от значения `objavlenije`.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: а с таким запросом можно что-то придумать? SELECT * FROM system_news ORDER BY CASE objavlenije WHEN 'yes' THEN 1 WHEN 'no' THEN 2 END , putdate DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве альтернативы `JOIN`-у можно использовать `UNION`.
Однако из-за того что `ORDER BY` должен использоваться только для объединённой выборки, в этом случае нужно будет использовать "костыль" с `LIMIT`, чтобы сохранить порядок элементов из подзапросов:

```
(SELECT * FROM News WHERE objavlenije = 'yes' ORDER BY putdate LIMIT 10) 
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY putdate LIMIT 10000000)
```

Вместо `10000000` нужно подставить значение, которое будет заведомо больше количества записей в таблице.

[Пример в SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f53230/6).

Comment: а с таким запросом можно что-то придумать? SELECT * FROM `system_news` ORDER BY 
CASE objavlenije
WHEN  'yes'
THEN 1 
WHEN  'no'
THEN 2 
END , putdate DESC

Comment: "SELECT * FROM system_news" выполняется в   наборе классов, а дополнение к нему "ORDER BY CASE objavlenije WHEN 'yes' THEN 1 WHEN 'no' THEN 2 END , putdate DESC" можно редактировать

Comment: @vp111 а зачем с ним что-либо придумывать? Если бы вам не нужно было выводить именно 10 сообщений с `yes` вперёд, то можно бы было ограничиться просто `SELECT * FROM system_news ORDER BY objavlenije, putdate DESC`. А с данным условием у меня нет ни малейшего представления как это сделать за один `SELECT`.

Comment: просто есть фреймворк от SoftTime, а там такая конструкция $obj = new pager_mysql($tbl_news, "", "ORDER BY 
CASE objavlenije
WHEN  'yes'
THEN 1 
WHEN  'no'
THEN 2 
END , putdate DESC ", $pnumber, $page_link); Все это автоматически создает таблицу новостей с навигацией.

Comment: "то можно бы было ограничиться просто SELECT * FROM system_news ORDER BY objavlenije, putdate DESC" может так и сделаю

Answer (score 0):

`union` пересортирует выборку, `union all` - продублирует записи, если не делать что-то специально. Можно вот так сделать:

```
select * from News
    left join (
        Select id_news from News 
          where objavlenije = 'yes' 
          order by putdate 
          LIMIT 10
        ) top10 using(id_news)
order by if(top10.id_news is null, 1, 0), putdate
```

Comment: На самом деле, с помощью `UNION` можно это сделать ("что-то специально"). Немного костыльно будет выглядеть, но всё же.

Comment: Можно, конечно. Например, с помощью `union all` - надо просто исключить результат первой выборки, например, `not in subquery`. через `union` - ещё раз пересортировать. Можно ещё поглядеть, как именно `union` сортирует записи для исключения дублей и прыгать от этого. Можно через пользовательскую переменную. И ещё как-нибудь - способов много даже на не самом функциональном mysql.

Comment: Да не, обычным `UNION` (не `UNION ALL`). Если использовать  `UNION ALL` и использовать потом кучу фокусов/селектов для исключения дублей, то этот вариант, думаю, проиграет вашему и по производительности, и по внешнему виду. А если использовать обычный `UNION`, как это сделал автор удалённого ответа (и зачем только он его удалил?), то с маленьким костылём работать должно. Мне, что ли, теперь давать такой же ответ, как удалённый...